# Alternative map definition in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary

Today I discovered the Typescript 'map' type and I wanted to use it for declaring a key-value dictionary. I know I can do it using arrays, but it's just for playing around. What I want to do is to declare a variable to assign an icon class string to an object type, so:

iconForObjectType[OBJ_TYPE (number)]  ===> icon class (string)

The code is:

```
let iconForObjectType : { [obj_type : number] : string } = {};

iconForObjectType[ObjectTypes.OBJ_COMPUTER] = 'icon_computer';
iconForObjectType[ObjectTypes.OBJ_PRINTER] = 'icon_printer';
iconForObjectType[ObjectTypes.OBJ_SCANNER] = 'icon_scanner';
iconForObjectType[ObjectTypes.OBJ_MONITOR] = 'icon_monitor';
[ ETC ETC ]
```

This way of defining it is too repetitive. Is there an easier alternative like the following?

```
iconForObjectType = [
  ObjectTypes.OBJ_COMPUTER : 'icon_computer',
  ObjectTypes.OBJ_PRINTER : 'icon_printer',
  [ETC]
];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using key-value pairs in a literal then you want the curly brace:

```
iconForObjectType = {
  [ObjectTypes.OBJ_COMPUTER] : 'icon_computer',
  [ObjectTypes.OBJ_PRINTER] : 'icon_printer',
  // ...
};
```

After all, it's just an object with numeric keys.

EDIT:

Actually these are computed properties so you need the square brackets around the property key names.

Comment: Hi! I tried that before, but I got this error: `Type '{ ObjectTypes : any : 'icon_computer' : any : 'icon_printer' : any}' is not assignable to type '{[type : number ] : string }'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ObjectTypes' does not exist in type '{[type : number ] : string }'`. I think that the problem is the use of the enum 'ObjectTypes', if I change it for numbers, it works fine. BUT I need the enum, as it's got global parameters referenced in lots of places so I think I'll let it as is...

Comment: I updated the answer to show that you're using computed properties.  But what is the definition of `ObjectTypes`?  You need to provide a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want help.  There is probably a way to downcast the enum keys to numbers and have it work for you.

Comment: Sorry, here you have the ObjectTypes enum:

`export enum ObjectTypes {
  OBJ_COMPUTER = 21,
  OBJ_PRINTER = 22,
  OBJ_SCANNER = 23,

  // Lots more

  OBJ_ANY = -9999
}`
I declare it in a global options service that I import in all the app components. As you can see, internally it's only a list of numbers...

Comment: Okay, have you tried it with the brackets above after I edited my answer?  It should work for you now.